# Inserting '&' to a table through hibernate query

Tags: sql, hibernate

Inserting `&` into a column through hibernate query.

My query is:

```
insert into table_name (column_name) values ('Java & Oracle');
```

But its saving only `Java`.

Comment: Are you sure that's what gets sent to the DB server? Perhaps you need to recompile the project.

Comment: Looks correct to me. There must be something else wrong

Comment: Hi w0lf, Thank you. Yes its not taking the full data as I trying to pass it as request parameter. How can I fix the issue to pass the full data.

Comment: I agree with Shervin. There must be something wrong with the way you run the insert. Please post the complete code (**edit** your question, don't post code in comments)

Comment: @rojalinbiswal `&` is a special character in URL. You have to escape it.